# Как сделать замену в строке .txt файла без создания новой строки?

Tags: python

txt файл содержит список:

14.05.2019 картофель \n

20.05.2018 лук, морковь\n

11.05.2018 баклажан

попробовал решить задачу следующим образом:

```py
with open('E:/Gadgets/Список овощей.txt', "r+", encoding='cp1251') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

    for i in iter(contents):
        if "морковь" in i:
            new_vegetable = "капуста"
            f.write(i.replace("морковь", new_vegetable))
```

код замену осуществляет, но добавляет новую строку, а это не то, чего я добиваюсь

Comment: Не совсем понял, расшифруйте пожалуйста что значит "добавляет новую строку"? Пустую строку в файле? Или новый объект строки в памяти?

Comment: Считайте все, замените и перезапишите файл

Comment: замена в нужном месте происходит, но строка в которой произошла замена, добавляется к списку, т.е. было три строки, но добавляется ещё одна, и становится уже четыре строки, вместо трёх (в последней строке отображена замена)

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться таким вариантом.

```py
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.FileInput(path, inplace=True):
    line = line.replace("морковь", "капуста")
    print(line, end='')
```

Или так.

```py
with open(file_path, "r") as file:
    result_text = file.read().replace("морковь", "капуста")

with open(file_path, "w") as file:
    file.write(result_text)
```

Comment: ваш вариант сделает замену с перезаписью и для следующей строки, если в ней тоже значение будет: 14.05.2019 картофель \n 20.05.2018 лук, морковь\n 11.05.2018 баклажан, морковь\n    Нужно чтобы замена происходила в i строке, т.е. например, только во второй

Comment: А как определяется i строка? Первая встретившаяся?

Comment: по сути получается да, первая встретившаяся.

Comment: Если вы используете второй вариант, то можете просто поменять на `file.read().replace("морковь", "капуста", 1)`. Замена первого вхождения

Comment: если будут идеи для первого варианта, с удовольствием бы взглянул.в любом случае спасибо за примеры. Больше всего конечно же меня интересовало как поправить свой вариант для получения желаемого результата?